# c# text box in panel visiblity

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, panel

I am attempting to display a 5x5 grid of textboxes inside a panel. Upon clicking `Show`, empty textboxes will be empty (`visible: false;`) and non-empty ones will be displayed in their proper positions.

My current .aspx file:

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
      </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" onclick="btnShow_Click" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Code Behind:

```csharp
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare the array 
    //int[,] wsArray = new int[5, 5];
    //char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ' ', ' ' };

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    // Put HtmlTextWriter in using block because it needs to call Dispose.
    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        int number = 1;
        //hw.Write("<table>");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            //hw.Write("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                System.Random rnd = new Random();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = number.ToString();
                tb.MaxLength = 1;
                tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
                tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

                number++;                    
            }
            Literal lc = new Literal();
            lc.Text = "<br />";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lc);
        }
    }
}
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control text in Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            text.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            text.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean textbox.Text null or empty? If yes try string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text)

Comment: And why are you declaring an instance of System.Random that you do not use? Also you should not declare it within a loop.

Comment: hi there , sorry if my codes are messy because this code are being used at other applications which have similar concepts that what i am doing , forgot to clear it . Sorry =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the textbox first; *then* check its `Text` property.Try this inside the button handler, `btnShow_Click()`:

```
foreach (Control control in Panel1.Controls)
{
    var textBox = control as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

By the way, if you set `Visible=False` from server-side your site layout may (may not) break as the controls will not be rendered at all. In that case **replace** this line: `textBox.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text);` with the following:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
{
    textBox.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: hi there , thanks for the fast answer , it works man really appreciate it but the alignment is not. what i wanted . because i am doing a 5x5 grid textboxes in a panel . so when the rest of the null textboxses visible turns false , i need those textboxes which are not null to stay at its current position , for now , everything is being shifted to align from the left .  i duno if u understand what i am saying ( sorry for my bad english ) i m new to stackoverflow , don't know if its possible to post a screenshot in a comment to let u understand better .

Comment: Okay, check the updated answer; this should preserve the grid layout (if i did not misunderstand)